# Sending Notifications to Mobile Devices with in a 5 Meter Radius

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, proximity

I have been asked to look into the feasibility of sending notifications to mobile devices with in 5 or 10 meter radius of a booth at a trade show.  The client would like to be able to send to notifications to passers by at a trade show and would like to alert them of their booth.

I am aware this is possible of users have the client's mobile application installed, but they would like to also reach those that do not.

Looking into the various options, bluetooth would require pairing (and the antenna to be on), NFC is too new and therefore not supported on many devices, and scanning wi-fi signals would let the client know people are around.

I am looking into foursquare and/or Brightkite API's, but that still requires those applications to be installed on the users' device.

Has any one tried this, and succeeded (technically and legally)?

Comment: Tempted to vote down the question for being evil. Letting other people decide to send me notifications is the same as spam.

Comment: @DavidDunham I think you missed the point of the question.  I'm trying to convince the client its not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Bluetooth, the same way that some billboards broadcast to passers by e.g. http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn7883-billboards-beam-adverts-to-passing-cellphones.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with the current (popular) smartphone hardware available on the market.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of setting up proximity alerts : using cellular network or GPS.

GPS can give you a precise location : the accuracy on a good smartphone is theoretically in the 5-10 meters range, but very often it's more like 20 meters. It may also drain your battery quickly, especially if you are monitoring a lot of point of interest.

Cellular is cheaper battery-wise, but will only trigger when switching network cell, so accuracy is in kilometer.

There is a good discussion of the different options in the iOS documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

The Android equivalent is here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html